# Factory Reset my Ubuntu 12.04, need to recover data

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, reset

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was not booting, and was crashing at the screen where ubuntu loads with dots. Recovery mode feature wasn't working as well. I only had the option to factory reset and it worked. But after it resets, I am unable to see my old home folder and folders. Where can I find them, and how to open them?

Comment: What do you mean by factory reset?

Comment: factory reset option to restore ubuntu in the original state